# Unable to create a Oracle function for the given scenario

Tags: oracle, plsql

Trying to solve the following question:

Create a Function named 'find_balance' which takes invoice_id as input and returns the balance_status of type varchar.

Design rules:

1. If the balance of the given invoice id is equal to zero,then display the status as 'The payment has been Completed'
2. If the balance of the given invoice id is greater than zero,then display the status as amount 'yet to be paid' for example, If their `balance = 500` then display 500 yet to be paid

I had the following solutions, but none of it work:

Solution 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_balance ( invoice_id  IN  invoice_line.invoice_id%type) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS      balance_status invoice.status%type; 

        BEGIN

        SELECT 
        CASE WHEN balance = 0 THEN 'The payment has been Completed'
        CASE WHEN balance > 0 THEN TO_CHAR(balance) || ' yet to be paid'
        ELSE 'Invalid Payment'
        END tmp_status INTO balance_status
        FROM invoice inv 
        , invoice_line inl
        WHERE inv.id = inl.invoice_id
        AND inl.invoice_id = invoice_id;
        
        RETURN(balance_status);
        END find_balance;
```

Solution 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_balance ( invoice_id  IN  invoice_line.invoice_id%type) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS      balance_status invoice.status%type; 
        v_bal invoice.balance%type; // Assumed this is the way to create a local variable
        BEGIN
        SELECT balance INTO v_bal
        FROM invoice inv 
        , invoice_line inl
        WHERE inv.id = inl.invoice_id
        AND inl.invoice_id = invoice_id;
        
        IF      v_bal = 0 THEN balance_status := 'The payment has been Completed';
        ELSIF   v_bal > 0 THEN balance_status := TO_CHAR(v_bal) ||' yet to be paid';
        ELSE    balance_status := 'Invalid payment';
        END IF
        
        RETURN(balance_status);
        END find_balance;
```

Guess something is wrong syntactically, please correct me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1

The issue is that you had an extra `CASE` in your existing CASE statement.  Remove the extra `CASE` and your function should compile.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_balance (invoice_id IN invoice_line.invoice_id%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    balance_status   invoice.status%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
               WHEN balance = 0 THEN 'The payment has been Completed'
               WHEN balance > 0 THEN TO_CHAR (balance) || ' yet to be paid'
               ELSE 'Invalid Payment'
           END    tmp_status
      INTO balance_status
      FROM invoice inv, invoice_line inl
     WHERE inv.id = inl.invoice_id AND inl.invoice_id = invoice_id;

    RETURN (balance_status);
END find_balance;
```

#### Solution 2

Two Issues:

1. For single line comments in PL/SQL, you need to use `--`, not `//`
2. You are missing a `;` after your `END IF`

Fix those and this function should compile

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_balance (invoice_id IN invoice_line.invoice_id%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    balance_status   invoice.status%TYPE;
    v_bal            invoice.balance%TYPE;     -- Assumed this is the way to create a local variable
BEGIN
    SELECT balance
      INTO v_bal
      FROM invoice inv, invoice_line inl
     WHERE inv.id = inl.invoice_id AND inl.invoice_id = invoice_id;

    IF v_bal = 0
    THEN
        balance_status := 'The payment has been Completed';
    ELSIF v_bal > 0
    THEN
        balance_status := TO_CHAR (v_bal) || ' yet to be paid';
    ELSE
        balance_status := 'Invalid payment';
    END IF;

    RETURN (balance_status);
END find_balance;
```